# Why is my program is outputting '0' when run, even though it is not supposed too?

Tags: c++, if-statement, output

I am quite new to c++, and was just playing around with if statements, so I made this program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int getMax(int num1, int num2){

    if (num1>num2)
    {
        cout << num1 <<endl;
    }else{
        cout << num2 <<endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(){
    cout<<getMax(7,13)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My getMax function takes two parmeters and is supposed to output the greater of the 2 numbers — in this case 13. But instead of only outputting 13, it also outputs 0. Why is this happening?

Comment: `getMax` should not output max value, but return it.

Comment: count the number of `cout`s, take into account that two if them are in different branches... what did you expect `cout<<getMax(7,13)<<endl;` to do if not printing something on the screen?

Answer (score 8):

> But instead of only outputting 13, it also outputs 0. Why is this happening?

because in this statement:

```
cout<<getMax(7,13)<<endl;
```

you send to `cout` result of `getMax()` call which is `EXIT_SUCCESS` macro that evaluates to value 0.

Looks like your `getMax()` function should return max value instead of printing it:

```
int getMax(int num1, int num2)
{
     return num1 > num2 ? num1 : num2;
}
```

but you should use [`std::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) instead, or at least rename your function to `printMax()`

Comment: I've gotta ask, why doesn't it also call the `cout` calls within `getMax`? Is it because the output stream is being currently held by `int main`, hence it doesn't call it within the method?

Comment: @Frontear OP's code prints `13`,`0`.

Comment: @Frontear "why doesn't it also call the cout calls within getMax()" it does, and OP complains that 0 outputs **in addition to outputting 13**

Comment: I completely missed that part of your answer, never mind, sorry. Still learning a bit of C++ myself

Comment: Never knew, but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> it also outputs 0. Why is this happening?

Because you told it to:

```
cout << getMax(7,13) << endl;
```

This prints the return value of `getMax` to the standard output (and flushes) it. The return value is `EXIT_SUCCESS`, which is zero. If you don't want to print the return value, just invoke the function as

```
getMax(7, 13);
```

or change its implementation such that the greater value is returned, not printed out (this is what the name of the function suggests!).

Answer (score 0):

lubgr and Slava already explained why the program outputs 0, I just wanted to add that it is better programming style to do something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; //this is considered bad practice, it is better to use std::cout etc.

int getMax(int num1, int num2) {
    if (num1 > num2){
        return num1; //this makes the return 0 unnecessary
    }
    else if (num1 < num2) {
        return num2; //this makes the return 0 unnecessary
    }
    else {
        return num1; //case num1 == num2, it doesn't matter which num you return 
}

int main () {
   cout << getMax (7, 13) >> '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

I advise against unnecessary return statements (but not against return statements in general, they are better than direct output) as they can lead to pretty random errors that can be very hard to catch. Alternatively you can use a `void` function that doesn't return anything, this is considered common practice when only using the function to output something:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void getMax(int num1, int num2) {
    if (num1 > num2){
        std::cout << num1 << '\n';
    }
    else if (num1 < num2) {
        std::cout << num2 << '\n';
    }
}

int main () {
    getMax (7, 13);
    return 0;
}
```

As Guillaume mentioned in the comments it is generally better to use `return` statements and not use functions to output directly, so the first solution is better in this case.

Feel free to ask further questions if any arise.

Comment: I would add an else statement that handles the `==` case. Also the syntax for c++ is `else if`.

Comment: Thanks this is a bit better, I removed the downvote

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Sorry, I had gotten used to the python notation, I corrected the syntax errors. I am not quite sure what you mean by "Instead of encouraging returns, you output in a function that is supposed to return and not output.". From my knowledge ```void``` functions do not return anything and the ```int``` function in the answer uses return statements. Also I advise against returns that don't contribute to - and here even impede - the program / code, not against returns in general.